# UINavigationController set view height?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I subclassed `UINavigationController` and added a `UIView` to the bottom of its view in `viewDidLoad` (as a custom `UITabBar` or `UIToolbar`).

How do I set the height of the view of every `UIViewController` that this `UINavigationController` pushes?

Answer (score 2):

> How do I set the height of the view of every UIViewController that
>   this UINavigationController pushes?

View controllers don't have height -- the views they manage do.

To do what you propose, I suppose you override the accessors for the `delegate` property so that you could intercept any calls to `-navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:` and resize the child view controller. That doesn't seem like a very satisfying solution, though.

Do you have so many view controllers that you can't add your tool bar to each one's view hierarchy?

Comment: I could add the toolbar to every view controller's view, but then the toolbar has a push animation with the view controller's view. I want it to stay in place as the navigation controller pushes the next view.